# NameError: name 'true' is not defined - streamlit

Tags: python

I am doing a project to predict house prices and want to deploy using streamlit.

```
# Take the users input
Lot_Area = st.number_input('LotArea')
Year_Built = st.number_input('YearBuilt')
Total_rooms = st.number_input('TotRmsAbvGrd')
# store the inputs
features = [Lot_Area, Year_Built, Total_rooms]
# convert user inputs into an array fr the model
int_features = [int(x) for x in features]
final_features = [np.array(int_features)]


if st.button('Predict'):  # when the submit button is pressed
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)
    st.balloons()
    st.success(f'The house price is: $ {round(prediction[0], 2)}')
```

But when I am running in the terminal using `streamlit run app.py`, it is opening in my web browser but I am getting below error:

```
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
Traceback:
File "c:\users\anju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\ScriptRunner.py", line 322, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Anju\app.py", line 1468, in <module>
    "scrolled": true
```

Comment: Is app.py the script you mentioned? If so - what line Is 1468?

Answer (score 4):

You might have got this already, but here you go - you have probably misspelled Python Boolean constant `True`.

The lower case true is a valid free name available for variables. Try `True` instead of `true` and it should work!

Answer (score -2):

Hy,I was a similar kind of problem and after extensive research, I found that streamlit is not meant to rum from Jupyter notebook if you used a jupyter notebook then write it on a python script.I guess this mightt be your problem.
I solved my problem by uninstalling and reinstalling the streamlit.Hope this helps.